# Python: Building an efficient algorithm for scraping an item from any webpage

Tags: python, algorithm, screen-scraping

I am working in a project that must scrape a specific item (e.g. author name) from any given webpage. For this item I put suggested alternatives. then I write a function that scrape an item through the list - using 5 steps of search tags: 1- search in meta 2- search in itemprop 3- search in id 4- search in rel 5- search in script

```
  mylist=['authorname' , 'author name' , 'authors name' , 'written by', 
'article author' , 'book authors' , 'authored by' , 'author']

    url='https://www.architecturaldigest.com/story/before-after-bathroom-makeover-design-tips'

    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser") 

    def item_scraper(soup , mylist)
              For list_item in mylist:
                  if soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': list_item }) is not None:
                       item=soup.find('meta', attrs={'name' : list_item})['content']
                       return item_value
              For list_item in mylist:
                       # search in itemprop code
                       Return item_value
              For list_item in mylist:
                       # search in id code
                       Return item_value
              For list_item in mylist:
                       # search in rel code
                       Return item_value
              For list_item in mylist:
                       # search in script code
                       Return item_value 

item_scraper(soup , author_list )
```

Can this strategy work efficiently to scrape an item from webpage? And is it cover all the situations? Please advise me to develop it.

Comment: Please edit your question with a short, representative sample of your `soup`.

Comment: @JackFleeting Fleeting thank you, is it clear now?

Comment: A little more; but what's your expected output from that page?

Comment: I expected the author name, may be publish date, last update, publisher, objective... and so on. using the same function.

Comment: for any given webpage.